# Remove duplicates from javascript objects array based on object property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, javascript-objects

i want to remove duplicates from javascript 'objects array' based on object property value

```
  var data = [
    {
      "John Doe": "john33@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "William Smith": "william65@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "Robert Johnson": "robert99@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "John Smith": "john33@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "James Johnson": "james8@gmail.com",
    },
  ];
```

here in the 'data' array there are same emails for "John Doe" and "John Smith", i want to remove one object of theme.

Comment: You need to describe the output that you want, because you don't say which object you want to remove, for example retaining 'John Doe' and removing 'John Smith' would mean losing the 'johnsmith8@gmail.com' email address, which might not be intentional.

Comment: What if you have an additional `{ "Robert Miller": ["robert99@gmail.com"]}` at the end of your array, which record(s) do you want to remove?

Comment: i changed the 'data' array, now i want the below result from it
 var data = [
    {
      "John Doe": "john33@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "William Smith": "william65@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "Robert Johnson": "robert99@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "James Johnson": "james8@gmail.com",
    },
  ];

Comment: means i want to remove `{ "John Smith": "john33@gmail.com"}`

Comment: I adapted my answer for the new `data` your provided.

Comment: Please stop redefining the problem.  You're just wasting peoples time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), combined with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) as follows:

```js
 var data = [
    {
      "John Doe": "john33@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "William Smith": "william65@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "Robert Johnson": "robert99@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "John Smith": "john33@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "James Johnson": "james8@gmail.com",
    },
  ];

const result = data.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (!acc.map(x => Object.values(x)[0]).includes(Object.values(o)[0])) {
    acc.push(o);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```